# In Firestore, is it okay to set the documentID for a document in a users collection to be the user's uid?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am creating a database-backed application in native iOS. I see that there is a `User UID` attribute automatically generated by FirebaseAuth every time a user is created. Is it okay to use this `UID` as the `documentID` for a user in a dbUsers table?

My original firebase firestore schema had the `UID` being a field of the `dbUsers` collection, but this made it difficult to directly obtain information about the user since I no longer had a pointer (`currentUser!.uid`) to the user's document in the database and would have to perform a query and iterate over the querySnapshot. I'm wondering if there is a security risk or something else that would make this not a good idea.

[image: List of Firebase UIDs]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's OK.  In fact, it's very common to do this, as it makes it easy to write per-user security rules for that document.